# filter rows which does not have class attribute

Tags: jquery

this is my table and I need rows which don't have any class attribute

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr class="Hidden"><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

I am using this and tired

```
$(this).find('tbody').find('tr').filter(':not([attr_class])').each(function..
```

Comment: It should be `:not([class])`

Comment: You don't need `.filter`, just put it in the selector: `tr:not([class])`

Comment: Your filter is looking for rows which don't have `attr_class=...`

Comment: $(this).find('tbody').find('tr'):not([class]).each(function..    This gives me error

Comment: `find('tr:not([class])')`

Answer (score 0):

The name of the attribute is `class`, not `attr_class`. So it should be:

```
$(this).find('tbody').find('tr').filter(':not([class])').each(function..
```

which can be simplified to:

```
$(this).find('tbody tr:not([class])').each(function..
```

Comment: this works fine cheers, but I also need to check if it contains a class with name 'Visible'. It should check both either the class is present if yes then check for the class neme 'visible'.
$(this).find('tbody tr:not([class])').filter(".Visible").each(function () {..
I guess this wont work because it is filtering on the filter..
any suggestion?

Comment: @user10239717 You mean it should select elements that have either no class OR the "visible" class?

Comment: @user10239717 You need to use two different selectors for that. You can combine them with comma: `.find('tbody').find('tr.visible,tr:not([class])')`